# Norton Internet Security Has Removed All The Shortcuts From My Start Menu?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, start-menu, norton-internet-security

[image: No shortcuts]

First the Start Menu shortcuts were there, and then they disappeared. I'm using Norton Internet Security 18.6.0.29. I'm wondering if anyone else has this problem; perhaps it's a setting somewhere in Norton Internet Security?

I've been able to restore/access most of what I need, except for Internet Checkers, and Internet Spades.

Comment: Why do you presume Norton is the issue?  Can you get into System Restore and rollback one to a previous restore point?  That may undo the damage done by a faulty installation.

Comment: I think it was Norton because all of this happened after I purchased a norton subscription. I'll see how the system restore goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A virus does that. Right click the Start Menu, click Properties. Click Customize and check the options for the right-hand side of the start menu. Then click Start, type `cmd` and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to run as Administrator. Type `cd c:\Users` and press Enter. Then type `ATTRIB -h /s /d *.*` and press Enter. Many shortcuts will be DELETED as well from this virus, but this will unhide a majority of them

Comment: Some of these viruses backup the removed shortcuts to the user account temp folder, not sure why but they do.